# Where are my U1-synced Tomboy notes?

Tags: ubuntu-one, tomboy

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my EeePC.

I have used Tomboy Notes for several years, and I sync them with Ubuntu One. Now this morning it seems all my Notes have disappeared, but the notebooks are still there.

What happened? How can I recover the lost notes?

Comment: Hi. Did you check your online U1 files? You can do so by opening U1 and following the 'go to the web...' link. Can you tell us whether the files can be found there?

Comment: Tomboy notes are not web accessible, so this won't help.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to a few users today. Check (and make a safe backup of) the following folder:

```
.local/share/tomboy/Backup
```

Answer (score 1):

The syncing with Ubuntu One for Tomboy Notes is going to stop at the end of february.
See this [article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/ubuntu-one-announce-tomboy-note-sync-to-stop-working-late-february).

> Tomboy note syncing through Ubuntu One will stop working at the end of
>   February’s, the Ubuntu One team have announced.
>
> The change will mean that new notes added to Tomboy after this date
>   won’t sync to Ubuntu One, nor will existing notes ‘restore’ on a new
>   installation.

Maybe it has come a bit earlier for you?

Answer (score 1):

1. Quit Tomboy completely
2. Press Alt-F2, type "gnome-terminal", press "Enter" and then run:

   cp ~/.local/share/tomboy/Backup/* ~/.local/share/tomboy/
3. Start Tomboy
4. Your old deleted notes should show up in Tomboy now

If that does not work, you can try the following:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type "gnome-terminal", press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then run:

```
cd /tmp

wget http://people.canonical.com/~roman.yepishev/us/tomboy-recovery.py

python tomboy-recovery.py
```